# packagingExcludes and maven property variable

Tags: regex, maven, packaging

I have a folder structure as shown below under **src/main/webapp/**

[image]

I have a maven property **${sencha.env}** that can be either of development | testing or production. I want to exclude the others from the **build** directory while making WAR. I am trying the below but its not working. Please guide -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/build/${sencha.env}/BACK</directory>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
        <packagingExcludes>.sencha/**,app/**,ext/**,sass/**,%regex[build/(?!${sencha.env})]</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please notice :
**%regex[build/(?!${sencha.env})]** in packagingExcludes

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close; you need to have `%regex[build/(?!${sencha.env}/).*]`. Notice the `.*` which means that you are excluding every path below `build/(?!${sencha.env}/`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/build/${sencha.env}/BACK</directory>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
        <packagingExcludes>.sencha/**,app/**,ext/**,sass/**,%regex[build/(?!${sencha.env}/).*]</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```